# DirectWrite text position different by font size

Tags: c++, winapi, directwrite

I'm using DirectWrite to render some text to a window. Everything seems to work except positioning when using different font sizes: I'd expect 2 texts with font size v1 and v2 and both with (x, y) = (0, 0) to be at the top left but as you can see:

[image]

neither "Test" nor "X" are really at the top left.

Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: it has to do with a spacing which is defined inside the font and should respect the actual size, that's why you see that with 'Test' is bigger then with X.. I believe it should be a way to control this within directdraw but honestly dont have much experience with that

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Welcome to the world of fonts. Fonts are probably the most difficult thing to use, because there is surprises in font themselves ( there is so many new standards that supposed to solves everything and just confuse more because almost no font support it at 100%, even some 'classic' font have partial/bad information in them) the GDI, GDI+, DirectDraw don't draw font at the same position in pixels because of math, coordinate rounding, anti-aliasing... ( you can have one more bonus if you do the math with freetype ).

When you try to print the font there are other pb. So the only way around this is for me. Don't even try to draw font at certain pixel coordinates. Do your job at drawing font, picture, lines on the screen that render well, do your best to convert them to printing coordinate for exports but never expect to control pixel in fonts, everything is round approximates.

PS : Don't trust internal fields in fonts. On Arial they are good on all other fonts some are missing or initialised to zero, but the "fun" part it's not always the same field which are not present it depends of the fonts. You could only use the fields if you try them before by font. Yes fonts are fantastic!

Comment: So you're saying there's no general solution ( for all fonts and font sizes ) ? God damn...

Comment: 100% generic sorry but we haven't found any way.You can find the bounding box for character or a word but can't be sure of exact font position. In word for example I'm pretty sure that the underline is made by hand because otherwise it wouldn't be a perfect line with different fonts/size. For a rendering engine using font in GDI, Direct2D and PDF bounding box was sufficient to have perfect look. But sometime in screen the letter aren't exactly where you want.

Comment: "You can find the bounding box for character or a word" I guess that'll have to do. How do I do that?

Comment: In GDI DrawText DT_CALCRECT will give you the box. In D2D it's a bit more complicated Hope that it could helps you http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd941773%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 2):

The term @evilruff is referring to is called 'internal leading'.  You can use [IDWriteFontFace::GetMetrics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371011%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or possibly [IDWriteFontFace::GetDesignGlyphMetrics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd370986%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get this value (for GetMetrics, the value you're looking for is most likely `metrics.ascent - metrics.capHeight`).

The values here are in Font Design Units, not pixels (of any sort).  You can convert these values to em height by dividing by `metrics.designUnitsPerEm`; typically, font sizes in DirectWrite are specified by the pixel size of the (lowercase) m; so if you multiply the values in ems by the font size, you should get the values in pixels.

Comment: This subtraction gives me something around 700 ( for some font and fontsize combination ) which is a huge offset so I'm guessing it's not in pixels? If not, how do I convert it? Thanks for your answer !

Comment: Updated answer to add conversion.

Comment: Dividing by unitsPerEm and then multiplying by the font size seems to always give 0, doing this on the other hand is close to perfect: float ratio = fontSize / (float)metrics.designUnitsPerEm;
float offset = (metrics.ascent - metrics.capHeight) * ratio; but still not good enough. Any other ideas?

Comment: Not really.  I found most of the data via Bing (e.g., "convert Font Design Units to pixels").  By 'close to perfect', do you mean that it's off by a pixel or two? You might want to look at your rounding in that case.

Comment: By 'close to perfect' I mean it's off on X by 4-5 pixels and ~15 on Y ( which, again, are different for other font sizes )

Comment: Windows (and hence many fonts installed in it) support Unicode. Did you consider that there are some glyphs like 'Ť' or 'É' for example, which need more space at the top?

Comment: Check line gap. The necessary delta should be
(metrics.ascent + metrics.lineGap - metrics.capHeight) * fontEmSize / metrics.designUnitsPerEm

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are using an IDWriteTextLayout in conjunction with DrawTextLayout (rather than creating your own DWRITE_GLYPH_RUN). IDWriteTextLayout aligns glyphs to their layout cell (including the full ascent and line gap), not the glyph ink, and this is true of pretty much all text layouts, be they web browsers or word processors or simple edit controls. If they did not (instead aligning to the top of the letter), then diacritics in words like Ťhis would be clipped.

If you always want to align to the ink, create an IDWriteTextLayout, call IDWriteTextLayout::GetOverhangMetrics, and then call DrawTextLayout with an origin equal to negative DWRITE_OVERHANG_METRICS::left&top. If you want to align to the cap-height always (that way "hello" and "Hello" would both draw at the same vertical coordinate), then Eric's approach will work.